# How to prepare postgres db for testing in kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a postgres cluster running on kubernetes that has been created by https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator. 
During the deployment process on CD I would like to execute some statements, for instance, create, insert, etc. for preparing the database for services.

The sql file could contain the following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE public.genders
(
    id "char" NOT NULL,
    text character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE public.genders
    OWNER to dbuser;



CREATE TABLE public.interests
(
    id smallserial NOT NULL,
    interest character varying(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE public.interests
    OWNER to dbuser;
```

The question is, how to apply the sql file on postgres cluster? Do I need the psql client?

Comment: That seems like an application-level concern, not the job of the database cluster itself. How do you run your migrations in any other environment?

Comment: @jonrsharpe To be honestly, I do not know. What your suggestion? How should do it?

Comment: You don't know what? If you mean how to apply database migrations, try researching "database migrations <technology or framework>". For example I have used liquibase and flyway with Java/Kotlin Spring apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you are right. you have to have a psql client installed either locally or in container.

First approach:
Install a psql client in you host machine from where you can access kube api using kubectl command.
then forward you database service port like

```
kubectl -n pgo port-forward svc/postgresdb-servicename 5432:5432
```

then connect using below command and run the query

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres postgres(db name)
```

second approach:
 you can do the same using docker image like

```
 kubectl run -it --rm --image=postgres:12-alpine psql bash
```

and then connect using below command and run the query

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres postgres(db name)
```